# Face dissapeared after adding a new color to it

Tags: materials, faces, color

I recently downloaded the latest version of Blender because I wanted to create assets for my game in Unity. After doing some tutorials for making a simple sword I wanted to paint it, but when I set a colored material on let's say the handel the faces I place it on dissapears. In the pictures I attached the same happens with the standard cube in the beginning. I still can select the faces but they just look transparant. Can someone help me out here? I already tryed Flipping the face and changing the alpha but nothing happened.

*First with normal material*
[image: First with normal material]

Now with a material that I colored
[image: Now with a material that I colored]